# Generate json file from folder tree using broccoli

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, broccolijs

I'm trying to generate a json file base on a folder tree containing json files using broccoli.

I found the module `broccoli-json-concat` that does the job well but generates a `.js` file that contains a javascript object.

I'm pretty newbie using broccoli and I was wondering what's the best way to generate a `.json` file instead of a `.js` file based on this? Should I use this module or maybe another one?

Basically this is what I've done so far in my `Brocfile.js`:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var jsonConcat = require('broccoli-json-concat');

var app = new EmberApp();
var jsonTree = jsonConcat('content/en', {outputFile: 'content/en.js', variableName: 'window.mycontent'});

module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), jsonTree]);
```

Thanks.